# Preserve Line Breaks For SQL Insert - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a textarea that is submitted via post.  Before inserting it I am doing this:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($notes)
```

And I am outputting the retrieved record with:

```
stripslashes($notes)
```

However when I do the line breaks are removed and I get one giant paragraph.

What is the proper method to store a textarea with linebreaks and output the retrieved data?

Not sure if it matters but I am inserting to a Mssql database.

Comment: Look at the source of the output. In HTML, the browser won't display the line breaks. If you want to display the text with breaks in html, you can use the `nl2br` function to insert `<br>` tags in place of the line breaks.

Comment: Could it be the linebreaks are still there but not visible in a browser but only in the sourcecode? Easy fix: `nl2br(stripslashes($notes))`

Comment: Hmmm I must be doing something wrong on the insert side of things, because my previous research suggested nl2br(stripslashes($notes)) should work, but it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stripslashes` is definately not the way to output to html, to escape untrusted input, use `htmlspecialchars`.

Best way is to make use of `white-space` css rule:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($notes) ?></div>
```

If you see extra slashes on output, you have wrong data in database. Fix that, not the output.